# Number of ways to legally insert n pairs of parentheses into a string of k elements

Tags: combinatorics

Perhaps I'm not very good a googling questions like this, but I can't find anything to help me with this.

Suppose I have a string of $k$ elements, and now I want to 'legally' insert $n$ pairs of parenthesis. By 'legally' I mean that the parentheses must contain an element of the string, but they can be `double paired' and nested. For example, $()ab(c)$ is illegal, while $(a)(b)c, ((ab))c, (a(bc)d)$ are legal.

I have found formulae for inserting one or two pairs of parentheses into a string, and similarly, the Catalan numbers enumerate the ways pairs of parentheses can be arranged, but they don't answer this question in particular.

I feel this is a common question that has probably already made it to StackExchange, so if anyone could at least point me in the right direction that would be great, thankyou!

(This is not homework, but I'm also happy for you to make me work for my solution).

Comment: Is only double pair allowed or can they be nested too? For example, is $(a(bc)d)$ allowed?

Comment: Yes, they can be nested, I have edited the above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the number be $F(k,n)$.
Either a sequence starts with a letter; there are $F(k-1,n)$ of those, or it starts with a bracket which eventally closes, so
$$F(k,n)=F(k-1,n)+\sum_{p=1}^{k}\sum_{q=0}^{n-1}F(p,q)F(k-p,n-1-q)$$
The generating function $$G(x,y)=\sum_k\sum_nF(k,n)x^ky^n$$  obeys the equation
$$G(x,y)=1+xG(x,y)+yG(x,y)(G(x,y)-1)$$
Solve this quadratic, and find G's Taylor series.

Comment: Thankyou for your help! How do I see that the generating function obeys that equation?

Comment: Ah I think I get it, very nice.